# Responsive Custom Shape div footer

Tags: css, footer, css-shapes

one of my website have a custom shape footer, is this possible to do purely in css? im going to apply this in a bootstrap container-fluid, so the shape should stretch to the container-fluid.

Thanks in advance!

[FOOTER SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx6XR.jpg)

[UPDATED FOOTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCkbg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.The Html code:

```
  <div class="footer-outer">
    <span class="footer-arrow"></span> <!-- This is for the top part of the background -->
    <span class="footer-circle"></span> <!-- This is for the circle -->
    <div class="footer-inner">

    </div>
  </div>
```

2.The CSS code:

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.footer-outer { margin-top: 150px; height: 200px; background: #415061; position: relative; }

.footer-arrow { width: 0; height: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 0 200px 100px 200px; border-color: transparent transparent #415061 transparent; position: absolute; top: -100px; left: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }

.footer-circle { position: absolute; left: 50%; border-radius: 50%; margin-left: -40px; top: -140px; width: 80px; height: 80px; background: #eee; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
.footer-circle:before { content: ''; width: 26px; height: 26px; margin-left: -15px; position: absolute; top: 26px; left: 50%; -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg); border-top: 2px solid #415061; border-left: 2px solid #415061; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
.footer-circle:after { content: ''; width: 2px; height: 40px; margin-left: -2px; position: absolute; top: 23px; left: 50%; background: #415061; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }

.footer-inner { height: 300px; top: -100px; left: 0; right: 0; position: absolute; }
```

3.The jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  stretchArrow();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  stretchArrow();
});

function stretchArrow(){
  _width = Math.floor($(window).width() / 2);

  $('.footer-arrow').css('border-width', '0 ' + _width + 'px 100px ' + _width + 'px');
}
```

**4.If you want the arrow to be pointing down:**

**Change this CSS:**

```
.footer-circle:before { content: ''; width: 26px; height: 26px; margin-left: -15px; position: absolute; top: 26px; left: 50%; -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg); border-top: 2px solid #415061; border-left: 2px solid #415061; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
.footer-circle:after { content: ''; width: 2px; height: 40px; margin-left: -2px; position: absolute; top: 23px; left: 50%; background: #415061; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
```

**With this one:**

```
.footer-circle:before { content: ''; width: 26px; height: 26px; margin-left: -15px; position: absolute; top: 28px; left: 50%; -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg); border-bottom: 2px solid #415061; border-right: 2px solid #415061; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
.footer-circle:after { content: ''; width: 2px; height: 40px; margin-left: -2px; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 50%; background: #415061; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/874zxr6h/

**And a working example for the arrow pointing down:** https://jsfiddle.net/874zxr6h/1/

Comment: wow thanks for the quick feedback Viktor, tried it on fiddle and it works, 1 thing though, the top part does not stretch 100% though, it moves when i resized the browser, makes it stick on the left part of the browser, how do i make it stretch 100% width? here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/winmag27/ad4160gj/

Comment: I've updated the jQuery code. Please if you like my answer vote and approve it.

Comment: it works!!!! Thank you so much Viktor! much appreciated.:)

Comment: Hi Viktor would it be possible to add the circle with arrow in css? Thank you!
http://i.stack.imgur.com/KCkbg.jpg

Comment: wow thanks for the fiddle Viktor, really appreciate it.:)

Comment: Hi Viktor, how do i customize the css so that the arrow is pointing down? Thank you

Comment: I've updated my post with code for the arrow pointing down. The new changes are with bold text.

Comment: Thank you so much Viktor! Really appreciate all the help.